# How to remove duplicate values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I need help. Want to remove duplicate values from array in php.

```
$categoryTotal echoes 144 125 262 108 351 177 266 269 270 268 309 144 125 262 238 108
```

On using:

```
vardump()
```

I get

```
Array ( [0] => 144 [1] => 125 [2] => 262 [3] => 108 [4] => 351 [5] => 177 [6] => 266 [7] => 269 [8] => 270 [9] => 268 [10] => 309 [14] => 238 )
```

I used sort to sort the values in ascending order I get:

```
108 108 125 125 144 144 177 238 262 262 266 268 269 270 309 351
```

but then using `$categoryTotal=array_unique($categoryTotal,SORT_NUMERIC);` few values like `309 351` disappear.

Would like to know how to know out duplicate values from this array.

Comment: can you put the entire code, it's a little bit confusing here

Comment: Are those disappearing values integers, too, or are they strings... when mixing strings, ints and floats you might get unexpected results, which is stated in the docs

Answer (score 3):

Asked before.

```
$array = array(1, 2, 2, 3);
$array = array_unique($array); // Array is now (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks all.
Issue was i was running for ($i=0 to $i<count) rather than using foreach.Because of the same output of array was skipping few values.
By using for(range) instead of for each the loop used to break when the count or the range value matched the key of array.

Hope you understand.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `array_unique()` function, like this:

```
$noDuplicates = array_unique($categoryTotal);
```

[Docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).